# Can we use Ruby on Rails to develop a mobile app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby

Since Rails uses MVC architecture. I was wondering that if we can use Rails to develop a mobile app or any web app.

Out of MVC the 'M' and 'C' won't change to develop the mobile app right?
I mean the models and controllers will remain the same.

Only the view portion should be changed such that, instead of using html.erb files I want Java or Android SDK or whatever, to provide the UI for the mobile user.

Can someone enlighten me on this perspective?

Also I have been hearing about jRuby does it come into play for our mobile app development requirement?

Comment: Are you looking for an offline availability?

Comment: Perfect, that fits will with using a traditional web app that mimics a native app.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer to this question is going to depend on how you want to deploy this app. Do you want it running completely on the phone or can it be a web app disguised as an iphone/android app?

For the native app solution I'd checkout the [Rhodes Framework](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/). It's not RoR but you'll see that it's an MVC framework that feels similar. This will allow you to build native iphone/android apps using Ruby.

For the 2nd option, web app disguised as a mobile app, I'd recommend [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/). Sencha has done an amazing job mimicking the look and feel of native iphone/android apps with their Javascript library. With this solution it would be just like any other web app though it's targeted for android and iphone via it's UI.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "[Rhodes] is not available on the iPhone App Store." Certainly, applications created with Rhodes can be placed in the app store, and many already are there.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood how Rhodes works. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @rwilliams, do you have an updated list? Or do you think Rhodes Framework is still the best way to go for a native app on Android?

Comment: @rwilliams, I want to connect to a SQL database and just noticed that they require a RhoElements License to use their Javascript API which offers database connectivity. Or do they have a free API that supports connecting to a database? I want to develop a native Android app using a development environment that is free, preferably a similar MVC to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5):

I've created an example *rails* / *ember.js* App that is exported with *Phonegap*. It uses just the usual MVC architecture of a Rails and an Ember.js App. Maybe you will find it useful. It also implements token authentication based on ember-auth and several OAuth strategies.

Currently in de the devel branch: https://github.com/joscas/base_app/tree/devel

Heroku deploy: https://starter-app-staging.herokuapp.com (the desktop version)

Exported with [phonegap-rails](https://github.com/joscas/phonegap-rails) gem (of which I'm also the author) for assets, fix paths etc.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutly YES!

Ruby on Rails just a backend tech, is the same as what you plan to do for normal browser. There are only two things that you need to consider about mobile app. First is mobile browser's content size because you need to adjust your layout to fit the size. There is a HTML meta tag called viewport can help you.

Ex.

This script will tell user's browser that the content should be fit the devise size,initial-scale defines the viewport rate and maximum-scale defines how many times this page can scale, and user-scalble=0 means user cannot scale the page. More about viewport you can check the Mozilla's doc.

The other thing you need to consider is the HTML5 techs, but actually these aren't problems when you are using jQuery mobile. I recommend you to check their docs. This is very useful and clear for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

RubyonRails is web application framework - it is running on server and  user observer the result of application built on RubyOnRails inside browser(or Browser component), despite the fact that you can process on server just "M" from "MVC", and implement "V" and "C" fully on client side( in mobile browser).

In theory, you can fully deploy RubyOnRails application on client side( even RubyOnRails server and etc), but it will be rather expensive and hard, but it is could not be require in any rational project.

assuming:
There are two way you can choose:

1. Organize RubyonRails application on the server(process there Model), and process "V" and "C" on client side with any proper js libraries.
2. You can develop Ruby(not RubyOnRails application) - at least it is possible to develop for Android with JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can . Your view can be an web page/android/ ios application as view.

Comment: How can it be an application? Where do I enable that?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try jQuery Mobile (which is still in alpha by now) if it's just a matter of UI. If you need a tighter integration with your mobile, I don't think that running Rails would be efficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try using React Native, the backend technology can still be Ruby while the front-end can use React Native to build mobile app both Android and iOS.

[React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)